# What did "id" in Blogger API Json denotes?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, blogger

I need a small clarification in Blogger api. There are two id's in Json file, one denotes the ID of the blog but what next one denotes. 1) Is there any manipulation to enter a id value. 2) Can I use random numbers. 3) Can I use a same value for all id.

```
{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "id"  : "???????????????????"
  "blog": {
    "id": "###################"
  },
  "title": "Post One",
  "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
},
{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "id"  : "???????????????????"
  "blog": {
    "id": "###################"
  },
  "title": "Post Two",
  "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any value you want. It does not matter because **Blogger will generate the post ID without consideration to the value you set.** And yeah, you can use the same value multiple times without any problem.